# TypeScript make function output dependent on whether an input parameter is undefined or not

Tags: typescript

I have a function that takes an optional object as a parameter which has a key called `initialData`. The function does some processing and returns an object that contains a `data` key which can be `undefined` or can be of the generic type passed to the function.

Now what I want is that when `initialData` is provided to the options `data` would never be `undefined` in the output.

Here is a contrived example of what I was able to figure out so far, but it's not working as expected:

```ts
interface Options<Data = unknown> {
    initialData?: Data;
    prop1?: string;
}

interface OptionsWithInitialData <Data = unknown> extends Options<Data> {
    initialData: Data;
}

interface Result<Data = unknown> {
    data?: Data;
    key: string;
}

interface ResultWithData<Data = unknown> extends Result<Data> {
    data: Data;
}

type PossibleOptions<Data> = Options<Data> | OptionsWithInitialData<Data>;

function doSomething<Data, TOptions extends PossibleOptions<Data>>(key: string, options?: TOptions): TOptions extends OptionsWithInitialData<Data> ? ResultWithData<Data> : Result<Data> {
    return {
        data: options?.initialData,
        key,
    }
}

const result = doSomething('test', { initialData: { foo: 'bar' } })

// This should not throw an error
console.log(result.data.foo)

export { doSomething };
```

Also here is a [link to the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AInGHMgLzICuIA1iNgO4gB8yA3gFDK-KjAscADYkyAfgBcyMXADcPPuijZ0ARinI8YKKADmCgL5cuoSLEQoMWXHgDqggBYBJEIOAjZyYqXJVaDMxsyBAAHpAgACZ4aJg4%20D5k7Nx8-G5Cor7SskYmZtDwSMgAShB41MJgiX409IwsyYq8kb6aOU3IdBAAntLauiAGXMam4AWWJWUVYA5gjrLVlLWBDSHhEFExpeWV1Y2pLWTZvrlcYN3oKAAK2Hh4wABGwhDW8YSy7FSvtnvIAD6xGz4WYudIeTJkPYKLgwWgIIHISLYADK2AAthA5vpqgAaZAAFW%20%20DWEWiyBud0ezyJ718rFYAAour0tDp9HjVEC8JpCXFbABKaS8rkkjZkmkg1zuTy%20X7iSY7GZOBYfZDSbbTX4pPhQTHUKAgTgdA5ZZCct7iAB0Agyshxxr4zPtqWMIwQtjAyF1iqWSNRGKxgwZAHJINpg3iOGlpRC4NIozBsNhpMGHnAoMHkIYs-yTAB6PMExzAGJ4RzYCqRZCMT1zFRMZBwQ3QFRQLju-DYZ6W4TYPQM73TS2HOCWxPYXNcMLobBQT1Rv3ozHFwZZ6FAA) if you want to give it a try in the TypeScript playground.

Would love to understand what I am doing wrong and if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do achieve this by making use of function polymorphism and declaring a few different signatures for the `doSomething` function like,

```
interface Options {
  prop1?: string;
}

interface OptionsWithInitialData<Data = unknown> extends Options {
  initialData: Data;
}

interface Result<Data = unknown> {
  data?: Data;
  key: string;
}

interface ResultWithData<Data = unknown> extends Result<Data> {
  data: Data;
}

// No initial data, and you'll maybe get data
function doSomething<Data>(key: string, options?: Options): Result<Data>;

// With initial data, you'll always get data
function doSomething<Data>(
  key: string,
  options: OptionsWithInitialData<Data>
): ResultWithData<Data>;

// Implementation signature
function doSomething<Data>(
  key: string,
  options?: Options | OptionsWithInitialData<Data>
): Result<Data> | ResultWithData<Data> {
  return {
    data: options && 'initialData' in options ? options?.initialData : undefined,
    key,
  };
}
```

Comment: This does not work because options have many other properties apart from `initialData`, so some other options can be present with no `initialData`. The implementation you mentioned would result in an error if I try to do this: `const result = doSomething('test', { prop1: 'value' })`

Comment: @PrateekSurana this technique still works for that, you just need to refine the types and function signatures slightly. I have updated the example code I gave now, but this should be a technique that you can tweak to use in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [I modified your example playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAczAPYgM4A8AKgCJxhwB8yA3gFDKPKjBZwA2ZFA-AFzKlycANwMm6KNnQBGPsjxgooAOaiAvnTpgAnuhQYsuPAHVWACwCSIVsA5c4xe9QC8aALasCBnPkdDKADTIAOQsbJxCwdQAZLRijGG2ERT8ghTqmqCQsIgoAEoQeACu7GB%20FNT0TMgAJkJyaSLxyADWENr8CkogqnQaWrr5hSVgpmBm9uVUyK7ungXFpVOBIXUUUcixVUxrcKn2GQN6yAAK2Hh4wABG7BDeRsszaJg%20hI3UAD7PhvhjltbhSbvUR0GBFEAIH61bAAZWwbgg4xUUyCRHu%20GQEAAHpAQDU8N9Xo9XOi3k5KAAKNodeSKFRBKQ-PANUkASlSpMxOIgeIJpL%20VhsdiEj24yAWIz%20QKcyH4EqW7zi1SgiKKUBASuqOyE-EZr24ADpEsKKAFmtVqWbqmpkHACXAQNo%20poEEYwMgVYt3a4arD4YizCoKcFIApgkEaMwAUl7PxIzBsNh%20MErnAoMFkDa1KzNAB6XMCQMEvBmbAlGrIEDYd3jSQAd1tGugkigdFd%20GwtwN7GwygpnpGBt2BoT2BzdGx6GwUHdkd9cIRSJ6mZBQA) a little bit to get rid of the default `unknown` generics type and to make sure your specialized types definitely have `initialData` and `data` prop typed as `TData` (I would personally avoid trying to override interface props).

Second, the issue here I guess is that TypeScript has no way to infer your `TData` generic without manually specifying it on function call, so it falls back to `unknown` for `TData`.

[image]

So technically I guess your conditional type would work, but since `TData` of your return type is `unknown`, you can't really use it.

The difference to `useQuery` hook is that TypeScript there can automatically infer the `TData` type from the query functions return type.